# Present Continuous or Future Continuous

Tags: tense, sentence-choice

I want to say that I won't be there for the first two weeks of August (everything has been arranged).
Should I say:

> I am leaving for the first two weeks of August.

or

> I will be leaving for the first two weeks of August.

Comment: You cannot be **leaving** for  two weeks, but you can be **gone** for two weeks.   To **leave** is to depart from a place.  He left the room. He left town.

Comment: ..or **be away** for the first two weeks of August.